# Execution of CASE statement in SQL query

Tags: sql, case, processing-efficiency

Let's say we have a table named 'neighbors' that contains the variable 'name', and are selecting name and using a CASE statement to assign values to a second variable, 'age'. The syntax one can use for a CASE statement in SQL takes two different forms:

1) Simple CASE expression:

```
    CASE name   
        WHEN 'George' THEN 36   
        WHEN 'Alfred' THEN 40
        ELSE null   
    END as age
```

2) Searched CASE expression:

```
    CASE  
        WHEN name = 'George' THEN 36   
        WHEN name = 'Alfred' THEN 40
        ELSE null    
    END as age
```

The two statements are doing the same thing. My question is, how are these statements handled in memory? Are they handled the same, or may one be more efficient than the other?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql

Comment: Neither CASE expression is valid T-SQL

Comment: I edited the syntax according to @JohnHC corrections. The question stands.

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax is either

```
CASE name   
    WHEN 'George' THEN 36   
    WHEN 'Alfred' THEN 40
    ELSE null   
END  as age
```

or

```
CASE 
    WHEN name = 'George' THEN 36   
    WHEN name = 'Alfred' THEN 40
    ELSE null   
END  as age
```

The benefit of the latter is that it allows multiple columns to be evaluated:

```
CASE 
    WHEN name = 'George' and OtherColumn = 'Stuff' THEN 36   
    WHEN 'Alfred' THEN 40
    ELSE null   
END  as age
```

Comment: I edited my original post to use the correct syntax you provided. However, my question remains.

Comment: @silent_spec Performance-wise on a simple case like this, there is no difference. Have a read [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression) for more complex scenarios

Comment: Does the searched case expression read 'name' into memory twice whereas the simple case expressions reads it only once? If 'name' is large, there could be a performance difference depending on how/when columns are read into memory. That's what I'm trying to figure out..

Comment: @silent_spec In theory, each row is evaluated against each condition until a condition is met. In your basic example, there is no difference at all in this process. In a more complex example, there is more to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about in-memory representation or performance but the second way you can evaluate multiple conditions like

```
case 
  when condition1 and (condition2 or condition3) then blah
  else blah blah
end
```